# Opening a Context menu on long press for a View?

Tags: android, contextmenu, osmdroid

All the examples and questions I've seen regarding context menus have been where you register the context menu to a button or something similar. In my case I have a display sized View (OSMDroid map view) that has it's over long press gesture implemented that will pass in a pressed node in the map view. I want the long press to open a context menu so I can action on that node.

The issue is when I register the MapView for a context menu, the long press will fire when the view itself or a node on the view is pressed. e.g. it's registered for the view. (bad!)

If I don't register the context menu for the view, my long press will trigger fine only when a node is selected. (good!) HOWEVER I have no clue how to programmaticially display or trigger a context menu that's not registered first.

I just need to display a context menu on demand. Anyone have any suggestions? Thanks!

```
@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    this.mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    this.registerForContextMenu(this.mapView); // <-- This will register the entire view for a long press context menu
    ...
}
...

class NodeGestureListener implements OnItemGestureListener<NodeOverlayItem> {
    @Override
public boolean onItemLongPress(int index, NodeOverlayItem node) {
    openContextMenu(mapView);  // <-- This won't display anything
    return false;
}
}
...

@Override 
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {  
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.node_menu, menu);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EveryThing has it's own purpose and structure. So it is always better to use something as how it is supposed to be used. Same thing goes with the menu.

In your case I think if you want a immediate popup after a long click event without the context menu mechanism then better use a AlertDialog.

Comment: I'm using context menu properly. It's the view I'm stuck with that just triggers the onCreateContextMenu ahead of the long press listener. The existing MapView long press listener is doing its own default behavior. I'd prefer it wouldn't, but I figure it would be easier to just open a context menu when the long press is triggered.

Comment: And the AlertDialog isn't going to be enough. For one I choose ContextMenu so I could include a number of options, possibly dynamically.

Comment: you can create your custom dialog with whatever design you wat

Comment: I'll take a look at creating a custom dialog. I thought you were suggesting to use AlertDialog with its positive/negative prompts.

Comment: I just suggested for AlertDialog .. actually I meant to suggest dialog to use in this purpose. If default dialogs doesnt help then we can definitely create custom dialog

Comment: Ok, I'm giving it to you for the suggestion. I ended up writing a custom DialogFragment that worked. It was a bit of effort but worth it for the control in the end.

Answer (score 1):

You might look into the Action Bar.  Although it was developed for 3.0 , the support library makes it work on much older stuff. The [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) seem to indicate that the menu style
you're using is not preferred while the Action Bar is the way to go.  Bonus: I find it much easier to deal with than the old long-press menus.

Comment: I could use the action bar. I was kind of expecting that a menu might communicate more information than just a couple of buttons. The long presses are for nodes on my OSMdroid map, so I'm not sure what you mean by "old long-press menus".